# Customizing 'quipol' skin?

Tags: css, wordpress, api

I have a poll setup using a script to pull it into my WP page. Via http://quipol.com/

***EG*** `<script src="poolfromquipol">`

I've found the styles via firebug and have customized them accordingly within, but I'm wondering if there's a way I could implement them for the styles to *actually* take effect?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#quipol-container #quipol {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 464px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
}

#quipol-container #quipol #quipol-corner {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 65px;
    left: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    width: 65px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#quipol-container #quipol #quipol-corner a {
    background: none;
    display: none;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 9px 0 0 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 21px;
}

#quipol-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    height: 590px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
}
```

Anybody know how / where I can `display: none` some of the default styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be generating iframes to display the poll in. You will not be able to style the iframe (nor access it via JavaScript), as it's being accessed cross-domain.

This is often intentional, as they usually don't want you `display:none`ing their logos.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought - was just hopeful!